# Automating build tasks using eclipse / maven m2e

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, jar, customization

I am about to use maven to automate my builds. Unfortunately, I am not able to get all the features I want, even after reading several tutorials :(
I would be glad if somebody could explain a way I can achieve all my goals!
I want to automate 3 specific build tasks with several actions for a project from within eclipse, using m2e:

1. Build snapshot

   1. compile
   2. define current project version + date as version
   3. build jar file
   4. copy jar file into the local repository **in the project path itself** (§{project}/builds/)
2. Debug snapshot

   1. build snapshot as mentioned above
   2. copy jar file to plugins folder of a local test server
   3. build another project the current project depends on, copy its jar file to the plugins folder aswell
   4. launch server / connect to eclipse debugger *(I know how to do that, the previous steps are the important ones)*
3. Create release

   1. compile
   2. define current project version as version
   3. build jar file
   4. copy jar file into the local repository **in the project path itself**
   5. create javadoc
   6. copy source files and javadoc to an archive folder
   7. increase the project version (for example v6 -> v7)

As mentioned I don't need a perfect solution, just a way to realize this ;)
(Annotation: Chaining multiple launch configurations is not a problem.)

Edit:
Which sections of the pom.xml do I have to modify to realize these steps and how can I invoke them using an eclipse launch configuration?

Comment: You need to be more specific, e.g. regarding what exactly does not work or what features you can't get.

Answer (score 0):

Hi based on your requirements i can say the following:

1. Build Snapshots

Building a SNAPSHOT is usually the convention during development cycle.

1.1 just using the conventions.

1.2 Date as version

This is a bad idea, cause Maven has [some conventions](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html) how a version looks like (1.0-SNAPSHOT or 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT etc.)

1.3 Build jar file

Usually done by the jar life cycle (mvn package)

1.4 The local repository is on your home drive in ${HOME}/.m2/repository for all your projects. Technically you can do what you like but it's against the Maven conventions. The question is why do you need such thing?

2.1 Usual procedure

2.2 Usually a deployment is not a job for Maven but you can do such things by using cargo-maven-plugin (integration testing).

2.3 If you have dependencies between project you need CI solution like Jenkins to do such things otherwise you need to do this manually. But that is different from a multi-module build.

2.4 Integration testing different story. Depends on what exactly you like to do.

3.

1-7
  The maven-release-plugin will handle such things except copying to the project path itself which is against the conventions. For such purposes you need a repository manager.

I can recommand reading these books: http://www.sonatype.com/Support/Books

Comment: alright, thank you! But this raises some more questions: 1.2 How to make Snapshot builds different to previous builds? I don't want that they overwrite each other 1.4. because HOME is at my C:\ drive and the workspace is on my D:\ (data) drive, which is being backed up 2.2. alright, I would do it with ant, just thought it would be easier to use less tools 2.3. I don't want to use CI - I am working locally; but I will find a way around.